# Extract one element per array entry from Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have a array of elements to query from Mongo DB but each element has multiple entries in the DB. I have to extract only one element per array entry with the latest timestamp.

query

```
db.find({ idNo: { '$in': [ '1', '2', '3' ] }})
```

So DB has multiple entries for idNo : 1, I want to get the entry with the latest timestamp.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find max element inside an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54292286/find-max-element-inside-an-array)